# Using RegEx to Parse Substring

Tags: regex

My string is this:

> INGREDIENTS: CARBONATED WATER, SUGAR, CARAMEL COLOR, NATURAL FLAVOR, PHOSPHORIC ACID, SODIUM CITRATE, CAFFEINE, POTASSIUM SORBATE (PRESERVES FRESHNESS), MODIFIED FOOD STARCH.

My goal is this (`without INGREDIENTS: and the final period`):

> CARBONATED WATER, SUGAR, CARAMEL COLOR, NATURAL FLAVOR, PHOSPHORIC ACID, SODIUM CITRATE, CAFFEINE, POTASSIUM SORBATE (PRESERVES FRESHNESS), MODIFIED FOOD STARCH

I tried this:

> (INGREDIENTS: )([\w]*)(\.)

Could use some help figuring out the correct pattern. Thanks.

Comment: can your substring ( the one you're trying to capture ) contain `.` in it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Find: `INGREDIENTS: (.+?)\.`
- Replace: `$1`

Answer (score 1):

Javascript:

```
var regex = /INGREDIENTS: (.+?)\./
var text = "INGREDIENTS: CARBONATED WATER, SUGAR, CARAMEL COLOR, NATURAL FLAVOR, PHOSPHORIC ACID, SODIUM CITRATE, CAFFEINE, POTASSIUM SORBATE (PRESERVES FRESHNESS), MODIFIED FOOD STARCH."
text.replace(regex, "$1")
```